# Do I create an Observable from my service when I have to optionally use http Observable or a variable?

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, rxjs

I have a service that checks and API endpoint for status data.  There are situations where I do not need to to do the API call based on other local data.  This check happens in a few different components in the application.

Since I want to encapsulate the logic into the service - Do I have to create a custom Observer to return the variable to the components?

My method isClosed checks some local variables and based on that returns true or does the API call.

```
isClosed(): Observable<boolean> {
    let o: Observable<boolean>;


    if (myCustomLogic) {
      //do some stuff...
      //this is the api call (http.get) which returns Observable<boolean>
      o = this.checkClosed();

    } else {
      //based on myCustomLogic
      //I dont need to call the api, but I am 
      //assuming i still need an observable???
      o = new Observable((observer) => {
        console.log('Custom observer');
        observer.next(true);

        return {
          unsubscribe(): void {
            //i dont what to do here
          }
        };

      });
    }
    return o;
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understood the question, but what I think is that you can use Rxjs's function `of()` [here's a link to it](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of). Basically you can use it to make an observable by doing ex. `of(true)`, `of({name:'ted'})` and even functions. In this function you could just use `return of(true)` or `return of(false)`, since it expects one of the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you still need an observable that always emits true and completes.

This is so common use case, that there is already "shortcut" for this, named [of](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of), so basically your code can be shortened to:

```js
import { of } from "rxjs";
// ...
isClosed(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (myCustomLogic) {
      //do some stuff...
      //this is the api call (http.get) which returns Observable<boolean>
      return this.checkClosed();
    } else {
      return of(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know about of().